# How to bind to a property of a repeater-generated item outside of the repeater?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I would like to be able to bind to a property of an item generated by `Repeater` to do something with it, e.g. to show its coordinates. For that purpose I am using `itemAt()` like this:

```
ListModel {
    id: modelNodes

    ListElement { name: "Banana"; x: 100; y: 200 }
    ListElement { name: "Orange"; x: 150; y: 100 }
}

Repeater {
    id: foo
    model: modelNodes

    Rectangle {
        x: model.x; y: model.y
        width: textBox.implicitWidth + 20
        height: textBox.implicitHeight + 20
        color: "red"

        Drag.active: true

        Text {
            id: textBox
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "white"
            text: model.name + ": " + foo.itemAt(index).x
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
        }
    }
}

Text {
    id: moo

    Binding {
        target: moo
        property: "text"
        value: foo.itemAt(0).x + " -> " + foo.itemAt(1).x
    }
}
```

Inside the delegate this works fine, but when I attempt to use it outside of the Repeater (i.e. to bind moo's text to it), I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

How to fix this?

Comment: My guess would be that at the time it tries to do the binding, the Repeater hasn't constructed its items yet. Maybe try doing the binding within Component.onCompleted?

Comment: @JarMan, in `Component.onCompleted` I can write an expression, not a binding. The text is indeed shown, but not updated when I drag the rectangles.

Comment: You can make a binding in Component.onCompleted using `Qt.binding()`. See the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript).

Comment: Bingo! I've learned something new. :) Thank you very much! I would be glad to accept your answer, when you write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the `Binding` object doesn't work outside of the Repeater is because the Repeater has not constructed its items yet when the binding is being evaluated. To fix this, you can move the binding into the Component.onCompleted handler. Then just use the `Qt.binding()` function to do binding from javascript ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript)).

```
Text { 
    Component.onCompleted: { 
        text = Qt.binding(function() { return foo.itemAt(0).x + ", " + foo.itemAt(1).x }) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't.**
(or more precisely, you shouldn't)

Delegates shouldn't store state or data, just display it or be able to interact with it.
In your case what you are after is the data stored in the model.

Your solution should be to modify your model in your delegates and get the data from your model if you want.

I've created a small example of what I mean:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 640

    ListModel {
        id: modelNodes

        ListElement { name: "Banana"; x: 50; y: 50 }
        ListElement { name: "Orange"; x: 50; y: 100 }
    }

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 1
        Repeater {
            model: 2 // display 2 copy of the delegates for demonstration purposes

            Rectangle {
                color: "transparent"
                width: 300
                height: 300
                border.width: 1

                Repeater {
                    id: foo
                    model: modelNodes

                    Rectangle {
                        x: model.x; y: model.y
                        width: textBox.implicitWidth + 20
                        height: textBox.implicitHeight + 20
                        color: "red"

                        DragHandler {
                            dragThreshold: 0
                        }

                        onXChanged: model.x = x // modify model data when dragging
                        onYChanged: model.y = y

                        Text {
                            id: textBox
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            color: "white"
                            text: model.name + ": " + foo.itemAt(index).x
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Instantiator {
        model: modelNodes
        delegate: Binding { // the hacky solution to the initial problem.
            target: myText
            property: model.name.toLowerCase() + "Point"
            value: Qt.point(model.x, model.y)
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: myText
        property point bananaPoint
        property point orangePoint
        anchors.right: parent.right
        text: JSON.stringify(bananaPoint)
    }


    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: modelNodes
        delegate: Text {
            text: `${model.name} - (${model.x} - ${model.y})`
        }
    }

}
```

I've used a hacky solution to your initial problem with an `Instantiator` of `Binding`s, I don't really understand the usecase so that might not be the ideal solution. Here it creates a binding for every element of your model but that's weird. If you only want data from your first row, you may want to do `when: index === 0` in the `Binding`. I've created a third party library to get a cleaner code : https://github.com/okcerg/qmlmodelhelper

This will result in the following code for your outside `Text` (and allowing you to get rid of the weird Instantiator + Binding part):

```
Text {
    readonly property var firstRowData: modelNodes.ModelHelper.map(0)
    text: firstRowData.x + ", " + firstRowData.y
}
```

Note that my point about not storing data in delegates (or accessing them from outside) still stands for whatever solution you chose.

Comment: Why shouldn't I? I have shown a perfectly valid use case, when the delegate is dragable. How to access the current position otherwise? You certainly don't want this data stored in the model, because of the abundance of updates, which will take place when you drag the delegate around.